# EmberJS development in Docker

Tags: ember.js, docker, ember-cli

I am trying to get a working emberjs development environment in Docker on OSX. I was quite excited to try out Docker beta, which is supposed to bring almost native behaviour along with inotify support, but unfortunately my problems didn't go anywhere.

The issue that I am facing is related to ember-cli monitoring for file changes. On OSX it is using watchman with inotify and works great. Inside a docker container it doesn't seem to pickup changes in mounted volumes and any other solution like NodeWatcher is much slower.

The other problem, is that ember-cli feels a lot slow inside Docker container than on physical box.

Any ideas, suggestions on how to get a working dev stack will be greatly appreciated.